# Any alternative to BindingValidationError in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, inotifydataerrorinfo

I am developing the winRT application in C#.I am using INotifyDataErrorInfo for validation.so how can i handle the errors during validation.i mean there is an event called "BindingValidationError " in windows phone but this is removed from winRT.so is there any alternative to BindingValidationError??

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Application.DebugSettings.BindingFailed event if you want to diagnose bad bindings. For validation - you would probably need to do it all in your view model.